# Disable desktop Facebook notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

Recently I get Facebook notification such as friends' birthdays on my laptop with Windows 7 64-bit. (White rectangular box on the lower-right corner of the screen)
I'm using Chrome browser but don't have Facebook extension or something like that.

Why do I receive these notifications and how can I turn it off?

Comment: Probably a screenshot would be more helpful. I am not big on Facebook & haven't seen anything of that sort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely part of the notification engine in Chrome which Facebook can be attached to.

While on the Facebook page, click the green SSL lock at the left end of the address bar and check to see if notifications are enabled for the site:

[image: Facebook Permissions - Google Chrome]